# Is there a name for these type of functions ("defined by braces")?

Tags: functions, terminology

I often see functions that are defined in a way, as I like to call it using braces. For example:
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 g(x) & a \leq x \leq b\\
 h(x) & a>x \lor b<x\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $a$, $b$ are constants and $g(x)$, $h(x)$ are some random functions that depend on $x$.
(Note that they don't need to be functions, they can also be constants).

*Is there any special name for this type of functions that are defined in this way?*

Comment: A constant is a function....the constant function if you will

Comment: @Triatticus well...I learned two things today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *[piecewise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise)*.

Answer (score 0):

It is commonly called a  piecewise defined function.